# copy the rows and insert back into the table after changing the column value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a table customer, where I want to make a copy of the rows and reinsert into the same table but I have to update the values of a column with sysdate.

```
insert into customer(capture_date, date, first_name, last_name, zip_code) values(01-jun-2015, select date, first_name, last_name, zip_code from customer)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it directly in select part:

```
insert into customer(capture_date, date, first_name, last_name, zip_code) 
select to_date('2015-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), date, first_name, last_name, zip_code from customer
```